# Finding nullspace solutions in a weird way?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a 5 x 4 matrix with rank($A$) = 2. Thus, dim(N($A$)) = 2.

We know that $x_1=\begin{pmatrix}
-5 \\
3 \\
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$ is in the nullspace of $A$ and that the vectors $x_2=\begin{pmatrix} 4\\ 3\\ 3\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $x_3=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 4\\ 2\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ solve the system $Ax=\begin{pmatrix} \pi\\ -1\\ 0 \\ \sqrt{2} \\ 18\\ \end{pmatrix}$. Find a vector in N($A$) that is **not** a scalar multiple of $x_1$.

I understand that the solution to this, which is much more elegant than how I did it, is by simply finding $x_2-x_3$, as $A(x_2-x_3) = Ax_2 - Ax_3 = b - b = 0$, which shows that the vector $x_2-x_3$ is in the nullspace of $A$.

But I wondered if my way would also work, although it may seem stupid.

I recalled that $x_{\text{complete}} = x_{\text{particular}} + x_{\text{nullspace}},$ which I will abbreviate to $x = x_p + x_n$. Now I consider a unique complete solution (my notation on this may be off, and I apologize) $x$ such that $$x=x_2 + c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_n = x_3 + d_1 x_1 + d_2 x_n, c_1=d_2=1, c_2=d_1=0$$

My rationale was that I can build a complete solution $x$ from a particular solution and a linear combination of the nullspace vectors, and we hope to find $x_n$, which is the other vector in N($A$).

Here, I found that $x=\begin{pmatrix} 4\\ 3\\ 3\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -5\\ 3\\ 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 6\\ 4\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and that $\begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 6\\ 4\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 4\\ 2\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix}+x_n$. Thus, $x_n=\begin{pmatrix} -4\\ 2\\ 2\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$.

Obviously, this isn't the intended way to solve the problem, but I tried using this method for other matrices, and it seemed to work for all of them: the vector I found always solved $Ax=0$. Would this work for all matrices similar to $A$?

Comment: You chose $x_n = x_2+x_1-x_3$. Then

$$Ax_n = A(x_2+x_1-x_3) = Ax_2 + Ax_1-Ax_3 = b+0-b = 0$$